# info : How to make an iphone app read data from internet

Tags: iphone, database, web-applications, ipod

I want to develop an iPhone app that read data from the internet but I have no idea about how to put the data over the internet (simple web , server or a specific things for iphone) and how to fetch the data inside the app ...

I describe myself as Intermediate level in Database

Note: All I need from where start learning how to develop something like this

Thank you

Cheer Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone supports all the normal web technologies for communication. HTTP, SOAP, REST etc are all doable. For pretty much everything network related, I recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

It is powerful, well documented and easy to learn. You can download files, complete pages and even submit data with FORM protocols etc.

If you want to save data to the disk, the iPhone supports SQLite and has it's own technology called [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/CoreData_ObjC.pdf).

Parsing data is dead easy too. For JSON, use [YAJL](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc). For XML parsing or HTML scraping, use [XPathQuery](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) of [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) (TFHpple is a wrapper over XpathQuery that makes it a little easier to get running with).

If you have any other questions, just comment :)

Comment: Hi thank u for ur answer let say if  I have a textbox and the user write inside it my question is: can I make a selection from database over the internet on what he wrote using ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Basically, if you can get it with a normal web technology, there's a way to do it with ASIHTTPRequest. I don't know much about databases though, so I don't know how you would normally query it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ASI HTTP Request` library is pretty awesome:

```
- (IBAction)grabURL:(id)sender
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
}
```

See: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Otherwise you get to party with a verbose and painful `NSURLConnection`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Synchronous requests are never awesome.

Comment: Hah, will synchronous requests make for simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way to get data from the web is to use:

```
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Let's say that the response is a json object I would recommend you checking out this project:
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

It makes it real easy to parse the response.